# asp.net TreeView and jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How can I get selected node text and value of asp.net treeview via jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much an answer as a recommendation for that you consider abandoning the asp.net treeview and go with jstree (Cf. www.JSTree.com). It's much faster (generates far less and much cleaner markup), and highly extensible. We use it on a couple of production sites with large trees. Plus, the main developer is very attentive to answering questions in the Google group for the project.

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna be abandoning the .NET tree view too.