# Check if all checkbox is selected == false in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach(Listitem item in CheckboxList1.Items)
{
      if(item.Selected == true)
      { 
           return true;
      }
}
return false;
```

Is there a better way to check if all checkbox selected is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ very easily:

```
return CheckboxList1.Items
                    .Cast<ListItem>()
                    .Any(item => item.Selected);
```

(The call to `Cast` is required because `ListItemCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only the nongeneric collection interfaces.)

Comment: can anyone help me with this question too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590378/asp-net-treeview-and-jquery/4590397#4590397   or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586915/jquery-treeview-via-asp-net

Comment: Ok, now the more general question.. _would you_ use LINQ instead of vanilla for?

Comment: @bobobobo: For this situation? Absolutely. It expresses what's going on more clearly, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if ALL checkboxes are checked/unchecked you should use:

```
return CheckboxList1.Items
                    .Cast<ListItem>()
                    .All(item => item.Selected == False);//or True
```

Or Am I wrong ?

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx) The overload of `Any(Of TSource)(IEnumerable(Of TSource), Func(Of TSource, Boolean))` will return true on any item fullfilling the predicate.